# Sticky button width of table, sits above footer

Tags: jquery, css, position, sticky

I have a button inside a table I want to stick to the bottom of the screen, onscroll when the footer appears to sit above the footer. Button must also match the width of the table

I've got the button to stick to the bottom of the page and sit above the footer when it appears but can't get the width to match the table, only when it sits to the footer

https://codepen.io/ryannewell/pen/mdbparX

```
<body>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
.table {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px!important;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.footer {
  background-color:#26272b;
  padding:45px 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-btn-fixed {
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%!important;
    margin:auto; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0; 
    height: 45px;
    background: red center top repeat-x scroll;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1030;
    border: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 sidebar">
        <p>Sidebar</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 table">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><button class="sub-btn-fixed">Submit</button></td>
          </tr>        
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- /container -->

<footer class="footer"></footer>

<script>
     $(".sub-btn-fixed").css({'width':($(".table").width()+'px')});

    function checkOffset() {
      if ($('.sub-btn-fixed').offset().top + $('.sub-btn-fixed').height() >= 

    $('.footer').offset().top - 10) $('.sub-btn-fixed').css('position', 'absolute');
          if ($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('.footer').offset().top) $('.sub-btn-fixed').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
    }
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      checkOffset();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Button should be width of table but is 100% width of screen instead, unless it sits above footer

JSFiddle for this question: https://jsfiddle.net/4fm1rx7v/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: fixed;` from the `.sub-btn-fixed` CSS, like so:

```
.sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
.table {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px!important;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.footer {
  background-color:#26272b;
  padding:45px 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-btn-fixed {
    width: 100%!important;
    margin:auto; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0; 
    height: 45px;
    background: red center top repeat-x scroll;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1030;
    border: none;
    }
```

In addition, add the `colspan="3"` attribute to the HTML like so:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 sidebar">
        <p>Sidebar</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 table">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
          <tr >
            <td colspan="3"><button class="sub-btn-fixed">Submit</button></td>
          </tr>        
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- /container -->

<footer class="footer"></footer>

</body>
```

producing this result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @ekbrothers. I made these changes, and initially on the first scroll it works correctly but then goes to 100% width of the screen until a full scroll to the bottom of the page. I'm looking for the submit button to always be 100% width of the table.